# Find all the units, irreducibles and primes in the ring $\mathbb Z/10\mathbb Z$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

So I have a solution I want to see if my thought process is correct...

The ring is a commutative ring with identity but is not an integral domain.  The units of the ring are $\pm1= 1,\;3,\;7,\;9$.  I got these values from a multiplication table of elements of $\mathbb Z/10\mathbb Z$

Next we see $2=2\cdot6, 4=2\cdot7, 5=3\cdot5, 6=2\cdot8, 8=2\cdot9$.  Since $3$ and $9$ are units than $5$ and $9$ are irreducibles.

Finally we know $2,\;4,\;6,\;8$ divides $0,\;2,\;4,\;6,\;8$ and $5$ divides $0,\;5$ so  we see for example if $2\mid ab$ then $2\mid a$ or $2\mid b$ so all these elements are all primes.

If this is not the correct way of thinking is there is a better way let me know!

Comment: Units are $\pm1,\pm3$; and did you mean $\color{red}4=2\cdot7$?

Comment: Why are the units ±3? Is it since 3 is the +3 and 7 is -3?

Comment: $3\cdot7\equiv1$, $-3\cdot-7\equiv1$, or $3\cdot-3\equiv1$

Comment: Yes, $7\equiv-3\bmod10$

Comment: Units are usually not considered to be irreducibles, right? $5=5\times5$, so $5$ is not irreducible, right? I'd say there aren't any irreducibles.

Comment: Any thoughts about my comment?

Comment: Are you still here, 710744?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP has abandoned it.